# Matlab: Applying multiple colormaps to the same imagesc output

Tags: matlab

I have constructed a confusion matrix in Matlab and I wish to display it graphically.

Here is a good example of what I am trying to do: [How do I visualize a matrix with colors and values displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942892/how-do-i-visualize-a-matrix-with-colors-and-values-displayed)

However, I wish to apply one colormap to the diagonal (i.e. white to green) and one to the off-diagonal (i.e. white to red).

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you seen this? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073113/matlab-how-to-assign-different-colormaps-colorbars-to-different-surfaces-in-the?rq=1)
I think you could use the same process.

Comment: You could add a large enough constant to the diagonal and concatenate the two colormaps, say colormap1 and colormap2, so that the diagonal gets mapped to the upper part of the global colormap, corresponding to colormap2, and the off-diagonal entries are mapped to colormap1