# Adding two colorbar for a single plot

Tags: matlab, colorbar

I'm trying to add multiple colorbars within one set of axes. Here is one reproducible code :

```
figure;
load mandrill
image(X)
colorbar
x = linspace(1*pi,200);
y = x + 1;
hold on
scatter(x,y)
colorbar
```

The second colorbar replace the first colorbar.
Is any possibility exist to have both colorbars on the same figure ?

Thanks,

Comment: In this question: [Matlab: How to assign different colormaps/colorbars to different surfaces in the same Figure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073113/matlab-how-to-assign-different-colormaps-colorbars-to-different-surfaces-in-the) you will find a tutorial how to do what you want.

Comment: i try to use freezeColors but I have the following error : Error using patch
FaceVertexCData must be an Mx1 vector (indexed colors) or Mx3 matrix (RGB colors)

Error in specgraph.scattergroup/refresh (line 169)
        p = patch('Parent',double(this),...

Error in specgraph.scattergroup/schema>LdoDirtyAction (line 145)
  refresh(h);
 
Warning: Error occurred while evaluating listener callback. 
> In specgraph.scattergroup.schema>LdoMarkDirtyAction at 139
  In freezeColors at 157

Comment: I'm talking about the answer to the linked question, not what the OP asked in the question itself. You don't need `freezeColors`

Comment: THe only way I found is to use 2 subplots and to generate the "colorbar" with the following code gamme_coul=jet;
subplot(1,20,[20]);
hold on
for ucol=1:length(gamme_coul)
    scatter(1,ucol,15+(ucol),gamme_coul(ucol,:),'filled')
end